# where genymotion fingerprint

Tags: android, genymotion

Please Help I am trying to use the Android 6.0 Marshamallow Fingerprint API. Trying to test it on Genymotion Emulator first. I go to Settings > Security and I cant find any option to add a fingerprint. Does anyone know where to go to add one?

I am trying to run this sample code from Google on Fingerprint API.

Thank

Answer (score 7):

For testing purposes, Finger Touch can be tested on the Android emulator, but **not on Genymotion**.

Requisites:

- Android emulator running on Android M (API 23) or better (for instance, Nexus 5 API 23 Android Virtual Device).
- Android SDK Tools Revision 24.3 or better.

Then, go to settings and enable Screen Lock using a password like "123a". Then you can configure Screen Lock to use fingerprint. When asked for a fingerprint, open a terminal and enter:

```
$ adb -e emu finger touch <finger_id>
```

... where  is whatever string you choose as your finger signature, for instance 1155aa1155.

When testing fingerprint in your application, open again a terminal and enter:

```
$ adb -e emu finger touch <finger_id>
```

See:
http://www.genuinecoder.com/2016/05/emulating-fingerprint-android-emulator-api.html

Comment: You are right, genymotion emulator lacks fingerprint https://www.genymotion.com/blog/android-testing-showdown